# Is it possible to install iPhone apps on iPhone Simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

After installing xcode ios SDK I can now run iPhone Simulator. Now is it possible to install and run third party free iPhone apps such as Paper Glider just as you would on real iPhone and how to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nope, you cannot do that. The apps in the App Store are compiled for ARM; the simulator is for Intel CPUs. Oh, and also, note that it's a simulator, not an *emulator*.

Sorry to disappoint!